# How to access a variable between different play/hosts in the same playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am a newcomer to Ansible. We have ansible 2.9.7 in our environment.

I need help in accessing a variable between different hosts/play on the playbook. In below code, group of servers is passed here dynamically and creating tempfile directory for each hosts on the Ansible server.

In the second play, i am unable to access the tempfile directory name (stagingdir) for the hosts, probably i am not using the correct approach using hostvars.

Can you please help & guide me to access the stagingdir value of hosts in the first play from the second play below ?

```yaml
- hosts: "{{host}}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Create local staging dir
    local_action:
      module: tempfile
      state: directory
    register: stagingdir

  - name: print stdout in same play
    debug: msg="Value of the variable is {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].stagingdir.path }}"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: print stdout in next play
    debug: msg="Value of the variable is {{ hostvars[ "{{host}}" ].stagingdir.path }}"
```

This is the result I get:

```
# ansible-playbook test.yml -e "host=testhost"

PLAY [testhost] *************************************************

TASK [Create local staging dir] *************************************************
changed: [testhost -> localhost]

TASK [print stdout in same play] ************************************************
ok: [testhost] => {
    "msg": "Value of the variable is /tmp/ansible.IsLik6"
}

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************

TASK [print stdout in next play] ************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['{{host}}']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ooauto/ansible/test.yml': line 17, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: print stdout in next play\n    ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************
testhost   : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This does not have any influence on the problem and solution but.... => `We have ansible 2.9.7 in our environment`<= which means you are using a version of ansible which has been deprecated and does not receive any security update for over 2 years now. Using an up-to-date version following the now only officially supported installation mode is as easy as `pip install --upgrade ansible`.

Comment: Concerning your direct problem: 1) registered variables do not survive between plays. You will need to [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) for this to happen. 2) [Moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names). The correct syntax to get your variable is `{{ hostvars[host].the_name_of_your_set_fact }}`